# Saving multiple checkbox values into a database, but only last value gets saved

Tags: php, mysql

this is my form

```
      <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="atte[]" value="3" unchecked />
```

and this is my PHP

```
      <?php  
      if(isset($_POST['sub']))  
      {  
      $host="localhost";//host name  
      $username="root"; //database username  
      $word="";//database word  
      $db_name="meeting";//database name  
      $tbl_name="employee"; //table name  
      $con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$word","$db_name")or die("cannot connect");
      $checkbox1=$_POST['atte'];  
      $chk="";  
      foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
         {  
            $chk = $chk1;  
            $in_ch=mysqli_query($con,"update employee SET attendance = ''");  

      $in_ch=mysqli_query($con,"update employee SET attendance='present' where id='$chk'");  
         } 


      if($in_ch==1)  
         {  
          echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Attendance Successfully Saved!")';
            echo '</script>';


         }  
      else  
         {  
            echo'<script>alert("Not saved. Try again!")</script>';  
         }  
      }  
      ?>
```

the code only save the last value.

given that i the user selected multiple checkbox.

how to save the multiple values to mysql using the UPDATE query

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix that. Google can help.

Comment: I'll bet that the id column is AI.

Comment: use `mysqli_affected_rows()` for truthness and debug

Comment: @Fred-ii-  yes ID is Auto Incremented

Comment: @Fred-ii- i just did the mysqli_affected_rows($con); and it says affected 1 rows.

Comment: Use variables as variables. PHP is not bash. There is *no* reason to do `"$host"` in place of `$host`. It's also worth noting that `alert()` is one of the least friendly ways of conveying errors. Just put up a `<div>` and style it accordingly.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman im fully aware of that

Comment: I can only go with what your code says, and your code doesn't indicate that at all.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($checkbox1 as $chk)  
     {  
        $in_ch=mysqli_query($con,"update employee SET attendance = ''");  
        $in_ch=mysqli_query($con,"update employee SET attendance='present' where id=$chk");  
     }
```

Comment: only saved the last value

Comment: @RandyCorpuz Are you sure you selected multiple checkbox?

Comment: var_dump($checkbox1) before foreach loop,see what you get!

Comment: i check the checkbox with value of 1,2,3 and this is the var_dump
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" }

Comment: I try this on my computer,and it's works well,I don't know why you get that.

Comment: At last, I suggest you look the mysql query log,may be you can find the problem